# Pandas DataFrame: Groupby.First - Index limitation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below data frame t:

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame(data = (['AFG','Afghanistan',38928341],
                 ['CHE','Switzerland',8654618],
                ['SMR','San Marino', 33938]), columns = ['iso_code', 'location', 'population'])

g = t.groupby('location')
g.size()
```

I can see in each group there's only one record, which is expected.

However if I run below code it didn't populate any error message:

```
g.first(10)
```

It shows

```
    population
location    
Afghanistan 38928341
San Marino  33938
Switzerland 8654618
```

My understanding is the first(n) for a group is the nth record for this group but each of my location group has only one record - so how did pandas give me that record?

Thanks

Comment: did you read the docs for the function? first returns the first of group values. in the docs, there is no `n`  or number of rows to return. if you want the nth row or n rows, have a look at the `nth` function for groupby

Comment: The first parameter of [groupby first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) is `numeric_only` which expects a boolean value. However since you passed the number 10, this is equivalent to `g.first(numeric_only=10)`. Since 10 is a non-zero value it is considered `truthy` so what you've actually done is aggregated the first numeric value in each group. Which is not what you were looking to do, but that is the reason it did not produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `g.nth(10)`.

`g.first(10)` is **NOT** doing what you think it is. The first (optional) parameter of `first` is `numeric_only` and takes a boolean, so you're actually running `g.first(numeric_only=True)` as `bool(10)` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

After read the comments from mozway and Henry Ecker/ sammywemmy I finally got it.

```
t = pd.DataFrame(data = (['AFG','Afghanistan',38928341,'A1'],
                 ['CHE','Switzerland',8654618,'C1'],
                ['SMR','San Marino', 33938,'S1'],
                 ['AFG','Afghanistan',38928342,'A2'] ,
                         ['AFG','Afghanistan',38928343, 'A3']  ), columns = ['iso_code', 'location', 'population', 'code'])
g = t.groupby('location')
```

Then

```
g.nth(0)
g.nth(1)
g.first(True)
g.first(False)
g.first(min_countint=2)
```

shows the difference